# ArcGIS for iOS slowdown after update

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-ios

My polygon feature layer hosted on Arcgis.com (ArcGIS Online) is slow to load on iPads and iPhones after the latest ArcGIS for iOS update (version 10.1.2 August 6, 2013).  If you search for Taupo Fire Jurisdictions within the ArcGIS for IOS app and try to open it you might (hopefully?) experience the delay on your device too.

It was working without issues prior to the ArcGIS for IOS update this morning (NZ).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Esri released the new ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS 10.2. The API supports developing applications for iOS 7 now.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/ios/info/what-s-new-10-2-.htm